# How do game store data like the storyline?

Tags: storage, game-development

I'm looking into creating a visual novel as my first game as it should be a fairly simple start, but I cant find any resources on how gamedata is stored, I could easily set up a txt file with all the story but that just doesn't seem to be how games handle it, how do game store storyline on a general basis?

Comment: This depends very much on your game engine. Tell us something more about what you are using. A text file is totally a possibility, depending on the complexity of your game - is it mostly dialog, are there cut scenes, FMV, audio? The answer will differ a lot from game to game.

Comment: It's mostly just text dialogue, I'm using javafx, not neccisarily because its the best tool for the job but because it is what I've been learning in class and I can see how it could easily do it, the game would be very simple so a text file would work but it didn't seem professional

Comment: use whatever is the simplest thing you can get away with. if that's a text file, use a text file. if it was audio, you'd use mp3 files, wouldn't you? don't worry about looking professional or not. plenty of games don't look professional. also, you're not professional yet, so nobody is going to judge you. the most important thing is always to finish the game.